# Loop a scanf while asking for a string with spaces

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char name[100];
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<3;i++){
      printf("\nEnter the name : ");

      scanf("%[^\n]",name);
   }
   printf ("\nName of Student : %s ",name);
}
```

I want this code to ask for the name 3 times however it only does so once, any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) check return value of `scanf()` to see on th 2nd 3rd time, nothing is read in  2) use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: late reply but what i did was scanf(" %[^\n]s",name); before i figured using the flush command would work.. guess not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char name[100];
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<3;i++){
      printf("\nEnter the name : ");

      scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);
  }
  printf ("\nName of Student : %s ",name);
}
```

The [] is the scanset character. [^\n] tells that while the input is not a newline ('\n') take input. Then with the %*c  it reads the newline character from the input buffer.

you can also use:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s",name);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use:

```
scanf("%[^\n]",name);
```

the newline character is left in the input stream. When the function is called the second and third time, `scanf` reads zero characters into the receiving argument.

Add a line to read and discard the newline character after that line.

```
getc();
```